# custom webdav implementation in IIS, gives 405 on PROPFIND

Tags: iis, webdav

I have created a custom webdav implementation with a HttpHandler, to serve files in a database via webdav protocol to a client. 
On Cassini, my VS Development server I can access this without problems.
Now I am trying to debug this site in IIS, and that doesn't work. 
I have the IIS 7.5 Webdav module uninstalled.

Some snippets of my web.config:

```
<system.web>
...
<httphandlers>
 <add type="Test.WebDAVHandler, Test" verb="*" path="*"></add>
</httphandlers>
...
</system.web>
<system.webserver>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule">
  </remove>
</modules>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="true">
<defaultdocument enabled="true">
   <files>
    <add value="example.aspx"></add>
   </files>
  </defaultdocument>
  <handlers accessPolicy="Read,Write,Execute,Script">
      <remove name="WebDAV">
   <add name=".NET Runtime" verb="*" path="*" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness64" requireAccess="None" resourceType="Unspecified" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" modules="IsapiModule">
  </add>
</handlers>

 </validation>
</system.webserver>
```

When I connect to this site by using the Map network drive option of Windows 7 and inspect the requests using Fiddler, I see that the after some authentication, the client does the following request:
OPTIONS localhost/explorer and gets the following (shortened) response.

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Allow: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST

I am missing some allowed verbs here, like PROPFIND.

The next request the client does is a PROPFIND. 
The server responds with a 405 Method not allowed. 
I looked at the request tracing, and the `DefaultDocumentModule` is causing this error.
When I disable this module, the `DirectoryListingModule` causes this 405.

Does anyone have a clue how to fix this, so that I can use webdav with my custom handler?

Comment: I get the same thing for a create directory

Comment: @jwdehaan: Any luck with this issue?